# Laravel factory specifying column twice

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5.1

I'm using factories for unit testing and so far I haven't had any problems until now:

```
// This is the factory definition (note: other fields removed for brevity).
// Primary key is not included just like Laravel's docs show.
$factory->define(Media::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'id_media' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber(6),
        'type' => $faker->randomNumber(1)
        // other irrelevant fields
    ];
});


 // This is how I call it on my unit test
 $count = 5;
 $id = 3;
 factory(Media::class, $count)->create([
      'id_media' => $id
 ]);
```

The problem is that this generates invalid SQL (`id_media` is there twice):

`INSERT INTO media (id_media, type, id_media) VALUES (73052, 2)`

If I don't override the id_media property when I call it in my unit test, then the query is valid but it's not what I need. Two things that strike me as odd are:

- I'm using this all over my tests but the only time invalid SQL is generated is with this factory. I've got around two dozen factories in my app and this is the only problematic one. This particular table has one primary key and no other indexes. The table is as vanilla as they come.
- This is actually recommended in [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database-testing#using-factories). I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Looks like when I typed the answer, I didn't actually paste the unit test code but typed it here instead. The problem was that even though the generated SQL had all columns in lower case, I miss-typed `id_media` as `Id_media` in the unit test as I was overriding the column value. When I changed it to all lower case it started working.